# 10-year visa ban

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans, deception

On my application I said that I have been refused a UK visa before, but failed to state the reasons for the refusal. I was refused a visa again under deceit and was given a 10-year ban. Is this a mistake, a deceit, and also can it be overturned under administrative review?

Comment: Can you post the image here, with your name and relevant details masked?

Comment: "Failed to state the reason" is not a deceit, but if you told the wrong reason, it is. But are you sure it is about that reason? Note: because you had a ban, they checked carefully every other documents. In any case, also if the case were overturned, I'm not sure you increase much the probabilities to get a visa in next 10 years.

Comment: We need to see the refusal letter to be sure but IMHO the deceit referred to is likely the one for which your *previous* application was refused. Subsequent applications that are subject to an automatic refusal because of a previous deceptive application typically refer back to the original refusal. If you’re still within the 10 year ban period they probably don’t even bother to fully assess your application. Even after the 10 years has passed, there’s no guarantee you’d get the visa.